# Linked in full Profile access 2023

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, linkedin-api

I am trying to get full profile detail of user from linked in.  like:-  Previous worked company's and etc, but all I can access is user lite profile,

and when I checked documantation of linked in it's saying that
Access to r_fullprofile is now closed. Consider requesting access to the r_liteprofile instead.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/references/v2/profile/full-profile

Dou u have any idea how can I get. r_fullprofile. from LinkedIn

right now I can get this data only

````
{
   "firstName":{
      "localized":{
         "en_US":"Bob"
      },
      "preferredLocale":{
         "country":"US",
         "language":"en"
      }
   },
   "localizedFirstName": "Bob",
   "headline":{
      "localized":{
         "en_US":"API Enthusiast at LinkedIn"
      },
      "preferredLocale":{
         "country":"US",
         "language":"en"
      }
   },
   "localizedHeadline": "API Enthusiast at LinkedIn",
   "vanityName": "bsmith",
   "id":"yrZCpj2Z12",
   "lastName":{
      "localized":{
         "en_US":"Smith"
      },
      "preferredLocale":{
         "country":"US",
         "language":"en"
      }
   },
   "localizedLastName": "Smith",
   "profilePicture": {
        "displayImage": "urn:li:digitalmediaAsset:C4D00AAAAbBCDEFGhiJ"
   }
}```


but i need all the detain in this object like education and experience
````